# Is the axiom of choice needed for constructing surjection from a subset?

Tags: functions, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Consider the statement 'Let $X \subseteq Y$. If $X$ is non-empty, then there exists a surjection $f : Y \to X$'. We prove this by showing there is a family of functions $\{f_a\}_{a \in X}$ where
$$
  f_a(x) = \begin{cases}
    x & \text{if $x \in X$} \\
    a & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
My question is: is the axiom of choice needed to either 1) construct this family of functions, or 2) prove the statement?

Comment: Your family $(f_a)_{a\in X}$ is uniquely defined hence doesn't need the axiom of choice. Moreover, you don't even need this family but only one of the $f_a$'s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The axiom of choice is not needed or used. We pick one element, so we only need Existential Instantiation. The rest is uniformly defined, so no choice is needed either.